# How to read properties as immutable strings in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I have been trying to read the read the properties in the Kotlin code. The `lateinit var` gets the work done but since it is mutable, the value can be changed even after initialisation. I want to read a property from a file and to not worry about it being changed anywhere in the file. I want something like `lateinit val` which is not present in Kotlin; or you somehow able to add `@Value` inside `by lazy` block of code.

I am working with AWS Secret Manager so I am putting the same code here but my doubt is more generic and **not** specific to AWS.

```
@Value("\${aws.secretsManager.region}")
private lateinit var region: String

@Bean(name = ["secretsManagerClient"])
fun secretsManagerClient(): SecretsManagerClient {
    return SecretsManagerClient.builder()
        .region(Region.of(region))
        .build()
}
```

I tried doing the similar thing with `by lazy`:

```
@Value("\${aws.secretsManager.region}")
private lateinit var region: String

private val awsRegion: Region by lazy {
    Region.of(region)
}

@Bean(name = ["secretsManagerClient"])
fun secretsManagerClient(): SecretsManagerClient {
    return SecretsManagerClient.builder()
        .region(awsRegion)
        .build()
}
```

The above codes are working fine but it would be much cleaner if there's a way to merge these 2 lines:

```
@Value("\${aws.secretsManager.region}")
private lateinit var region: String

private val awsRegion: Region by lazy {
    Region.of(region)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your specific case you can inject property directly into bean method as an argument (method arguments are immutable)

```kotlin
@Bean(name = ["secretsManagerClient"])
fun secretsManagerClient(
    @Value("\${aws.secretsManager.region}") region: String
): SecretsManagerClient {
    return SecretsManagerClient.builder()
        .region(Region.of(region))
        .build()
}
```

or if you need this property in multiple `@Bean`s you can inject it into constructor of enclosing configuration class

```kotlin
@Confiuration
class SomeConfig(
    @Value("\${aws.secretsManager.region}")
    private val region: String
) {

    @Bean(name = ["secretsManagerClient"])
    fun secretsManagerClient(): SecretsManagerClient {
        return SecretsManagerClient.builder()
            .region(Region.of(region))
            .build()
    }
}
```